# Handsontable Performance

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I am using handsontable 0.18.0 version in my application. In the handsontable we are loading collection of data in tree view form, We can expands their childs. If we expand the childs and update any particular cell, we are facing performance issue (it takes almost 20-30 secs) in IE browser, but in chrome it is 3-6 seconds. Without expanding nodes it will take around 3-5 Secs., only.

Can anyone suggest how to overcome this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One of the issues with IE is the way the virtual rendering occurs. The reason chrome and other browsers are so fast is that Handson uses this type of rendering to only show the rows in your viewport. It is a known issue which is why if you look at the compatibility table, it says IE is known to have "Limited ability to handle large amounts of data".

The solution would be to upgrade your browser or try to implement a type of virtual rendering yourself. The latter can be daunting but the only solution, unfortunately.

Comment: How do you implement virtual rendering? Any resource or link or documentation for the same?

Comment: I dont know that you'd want to do it. Either way, I've never tried myself so I wouldn't know.

Comment: I am using IE 11 and with some big data of around 500-1000 rows it starts locking up but in Chrome it is fine. Any resources you can forward me to?

Comment: No idea. I did a google search, got this: http://www.lab4games.net/zz85/blog/2012/06/23/virtual-rendering-1000000-items-efficiently/. Again though, it's a really complex feature. I recommend pagination instead of trying to setup virtual rendering yourself.